# Nginx config file only working for ''/"

Tags: nginx

I am setting up nginx as a sort of static file server.  For some reason it is only working when I go to 123.123.123.123/ or 123.123.123.123.  However, when I go to 123.123.123.123/static/content/ or 123.123.123.123/static/content/another.mp3 it returns a 404 not found.  Here is the config file that is located in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and linked to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.  I am really stumped as to why it is not working.

Any pointers or tips would be appreciated.

```
server {
    listen 123.123.123.123:80;
    server_name "";

     location / {
         root /srv/homepage;
         index  index.html;
     }

     location /static/content/ {
         root /srv/static/content;
         index  song.mp3;
     }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into logs.
Seems like nginx tries to open paths like /srv/static/content/static/content/file.mp3
You need to rewrite url here, try this:

rewrite    /static/content/(.*) /$1 break;

Comment: If I have a lot of link / static pages in my app? Do I need to rewrite the url for each one of them?